# Как лучше реализовать сохранение больших объёмов текста в android приложении?

Tags: android, android-studio, sqlite, listview, android-xml

Добрый день!

Вот суть проблемы: 
предположим, у меня есть приложение, в котором с помощью `ListView` выводится список названий городов.

Пользователь нажимает на него, открывается другая активность, в которой указаны: название города, страны, где он расположен, и 3-4 предложения для краткого его описания. Соотвественно, мне нужен список 60ти городов, стран, в которых эти города расположены, и 3-4 предложения для краткого описания каждого города.

Как лучше реализовать такие списки с учётом того, что описание города может быть довольно объёмным? Стоит ли использовать для этого `xml-файлы`, `SQLite(нежелательно)`, или есть другие, более подходящие варианты?

Comment: Решение все таки напрашивается на базу данных SQLite. Ее можно заполнить предварительно в любом SQL-менеджере, загрузить в assets, и подгрузить в приложение при первом входе.

Comment: Почему SQLite не желательно? Если обернуть ее в Room то вполне неплохо получится

Comment: Хорошо, попробую SQLite.

Comment: Кстати, что будет менее ресурсозатратным? Использование SQLite, или испольщование xml-файла в качестве хранилища?